# Funny 500 error when accessing page from php script

Tags: php, html, html-parsing, simple-html-dom

I would like to parse http://gmmobile.atm-mi.it/wsbw/InfoTraffico/ page which does not require authentication. Yet, when I try to access it through a PHP script in order to parse its content, I receive an error:

> Warning: file_get_contents(http://gmmobile.atm-mi.it/wsbw/InfoTraffico/) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error in /iPhone/simplehtmldom_1_5/simple_html_dom.php on line 70

The code I am using is the following:

```
include('simple_html_dom.php');
// Create DOM from URL or file
$url='http://gmmobile.atm-mi.it/wsbw/InfoTraffico/';
echo $url;
$html = file_get_html($url);
echo $html;
$i=0;
foreach($html->find('option') as $content) 
{
    $linea=$content->value;
    $destination=$content->title;
        $i++;

}
```

What might be the problem and how could I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a User-Agent:

```
$url = 'http://gmmobile.atm-mi.it/wsbw/InfoTraffico/';
$options = array('http' => array('header' => "User-Agent: myFooAgent\r\n"));
$context = stream_context_create($options);
echo file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
```

Comment: Thanks, I will have a look at the suggestions.

Comment: Many thanks and sorry for not implementing it promptly but I had to fix other issues and discovered the app I wanted to implement was already done.

Comment: You should close the question.

Comment: Very reasonable suggestion, but how do I do it?